# Windows Server 2022 does not enable BrainpoolP256r1 ECC curve

Tags: windows, cryptography, fips-140-2

I want to enable the ECC curve `BrainpoolP256r1` on a Windows Server 2022.

## expected bahavior

brainpool curve is added with enable command:

```perl
PS C:\> Get-TlsEccCurve
curve25519
NistP256
NistP384
PS C:\> Enable-TlsEccCurve BrainpoolP256r1
PS C:\> Get-TlsEccCurve
curve25519
NistP256
NistP384
BrainpoolP256r1 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

## actual behavior

the brainpool curve is **not** added! Also note `curve25519` is missing as well, which is available as a default on other machines I tested.

```perl
PS C:\> Get-TlsEccCurve
NistP384
NistP256
PS C:\> Enable-TlsEccCurve BrainpoolP256r1
PS C:\> Get-TlsEccCurve
NistP384
NistP256
```

## what I tried as well

According to [the docs on elliptic curves in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-elliptic-curves-in-windows-10-1607-and-later) my machine is showing me only the "Available in FIPS mode"-curves.

I looked in group policies, but "System cryptography: Use FIPS 140 compliant cryptographic algorithms, including encryption, hashing and signing algorithms" is disabled.

The machine is domain joined.

Comment: Check Group Policy. If configured there, it needs to be changed there and cannot be overridden by command.  `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Cryptography\Configuration\...` `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Network > SSL Configuration Settings > ECC Curve Order`. https://github.com/Crosse/SchannelGroupPolicy#usage

Comment: This sounds like a case for Microsoft support

Comment: As of FIPS186-5/SP800-186 this past Feb. curve25519 is added to 'FIPS' (meaning FIPS140) but I don't know if particular MS versions are updated for this. Brainpool curves remain non-FIPS. Why you are apparently getting FIPS restrictions when (you think) you shouldn't I don't know.

Comment: @GregAskew I setup the ecc curve order as you described and it solved my issue. I am only wondering why these machines behave differently. I would mark your comment as answer, but after all, it is only a comment, so I cant. Thank you anyway!